# comparison the slope for (3,4)

Tags: geometry, gre-exam

**The correct answer and the question is shown below:** [image]

Why the slope of k is always greater than 1 whereas as I determined the slope (3,4) by $$\tan x =  \frac{4}{3}$$ which is greater than 1. It seems that k slope is more steep than (3,4) so the slope of k would be more than 1 i think . Where have I done wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you did it wrong?  Your answer is correct.

Comment: The question I got from official gre powerprep 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope of the line through $(3,4)$ is $\frac 43$.  You don't need the tangent unless you want the actual angle.  But you are correct that the slope of the line drawn is greater than that and therefore greater than $1$.  What makes you think you are wrong?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I replaced the xy coordinates so I calculated wrongly.